# Set Border for selected text in FlowDocument

Tags: wpf, flowdocument, textrange

How can I change background style of selected text or a `TextRange` in `FlowDocument` and set Border with corner radius for it?

Something like this:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try add style for items:

```
<Style.Triggers>
     <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Color"/>
     </Trigger>
</Style.Triggers>
```

Comment: tanks, but I don't want to change foreground. as mentioned I want to set border for TextRange. I want to do it in code.

Comment: @Ali.M Hi, did you ever find a solution to this?